# Populate listbox from text file

Tags: c#, listbox

I am making an contact book to try to learn classes, and opening new forms.

I am trying to get items from a text document to populate a list box, using only the string before the first delimiter from each line. When I run the script, the Windows form appears, but the listbox is *blank* but there appears to be five items in it that are selectable. Clicking on them has no effect.

Here is my code for the form:

```
namespace AddressBook
    {
public partial class formMain : Form
    {
    //Pub vars
    string selectedName = "";
    List<string> values = new List<string>();

    public formMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void formMain_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //load values from file
        try
        {
        StreamReader inputFile;
        inputFile = File.OpenText("EmpRoster.txt");

        string lines;

        while (!inputfile.EndOfSteam)
        {
            lines = inputFile.ReadLine();
            string[] tokens = lines.Split(',');

            PersonEntry person = new PersonEntry(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);

            values.Add(person.Name + ";" + person.Email + ";" + person.Phone);

            listOuput.Items.Add(person.Name);
        }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    //Selected index change
    private void listOutput_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedName = listOutput.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Form newForm = new Form();

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Size = new Size(270, 75);
        label1.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        foreach (string str in values)
        {
        if (str.Containes(selectedName))
        {
            string[] tokens = str.Split(';');
            label1.text += "Name: " + tokens[0] + "\n" + "Email: " + tokens[1] + "\n" + "Phone Number: " + tokens[2] + "\n";
        }
        }
        newForm.Controls.Add(label1);
        newForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

and here is my code for the class:

```
namespace AddressBook
{
    public class PersonEntry
    {
    private string _name;
    private string _email;
    private string _phone;

    public PersonEntry(string name, string email, string phone)
    {
        _name = "";
        _email = "";
        _phone = "";
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set { _email = value; }
    {

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set { _phone = value; }
    }
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to get this to show at run; however, I did try adding a button and populating the listbox on click, and that seemed to work.

I'd appreciate some fresh eyes on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies on how you are instantiating your class. If you look at the constructor:

```
public PersonEntry(string name, string email, string phone)
{
    _name = "";
    _email = "";
    _phone = "";
}
```

You are not storing the received values, but ignoring them completely.  Just simplify your class to this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }

public PersonEntry(string name, string email, string phone)
{
    Name = name;
    Email = email;
    Phone = phone;
}
```

You don't need to generate the backing fields, that's done automatically for you.

Comment: This is correct, marked as answered. Any idea why the new form isn't popping up for SelectedIndexChanged?

Nevermind -- I didn't get the Event. Everything works as it should now. Thank ya!

Comment: @Exulansis Are you sure it's not popping up? I'd guess the SelectIndexChanged event it's not firing at all or you are not seeing it.

Comment: Edited that comment - I didn't set the event. It works now. Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Glad to be of help. As a little further tip, look up into `override ToString()` for this `PersonEntry` class

Answer (score 2):

Your PersonEntry constructor is the issue. You are assigning empty strings where you should (presumably) be assigning the supplied parameters.